# Extract timestamp from JSON and use it as the logstash event timestamp

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I hope somebody can help me out. Ik have the following setup:

```
shipper >> redis >> logstash >> elasticsearch
```

Logstash has an input, which extracts log data from redis. The following JSON line goes in redis:

```
{
  "@fields": {
    "level": "INFO",
    "mdc": {},
    "file": "ContextLoader.java",
    "class": "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader",
    "line_number": "273",
    "method": "initWebApplicationContext"
  },
  "@timestamp": "2013-12-18T11::29:29.115+01:00",
  "@message": "Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started",
  "@source_host": "test-host"
}
```

The logstash configuration I use is simple:

```
input {
  redis {
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash:test:host"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter{
  date {
    match => [ "@timestamp", "dd-MMM-YYYY:HH:mm:ssZ", "dd-MMM-YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z", "ISO8601" ]
  }
}
output {
  stdout{
    debug => true
  }
}
```

When I use the above configuration, I see that the timestamp of the logstash event is used `(2013-12-18T12:53:14.169Z)` and I get the following error from my debug screen:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"@timestamp", :value=>"2013-12-18T12:53:14.177Z", :exception=>#<TypeError: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyTime to class java.lang.String>, :level=>:warn}
```

From this, I can conclude the following:

When the log entry comes in as input, the timestamp of the json log entry is overwritten with the timestamp event of logstash. Then, when the date filter tries to parse the timestamp, it fails because, there is no match.

I want to use the timestamp of the json log entry as my logstash event timestamp. How can I achieve this? I use the logstash version 1.3.1.

Comment: Bug looks related: [LOGSTASH-1340: If filter replaces @timestamp with a string flushing of event fails](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1340). A few people have suggested workarounds you might try.

Comment: Yeah I think so. Thnx.

Comment: "T11::29:29" in your example must be a typo, or?

Comment: So, how did you solve it? Care to share? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have misunderstood how the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) (there don't appear to be docs for 1.3.1) works, it takes a field, and parses it against a pattern you set and uses that match to set the value of the @timestamp field (by default). Since you are taking the @timestamp field, matching it against a pattern and then trying to set the @timestamp field with it, what you're doing is redundant.

If you have a different timestamp field you want to take the date from I expect it would probably work, as long as you were using the right pattern for that field.

I would also recommend you update to 1.4.2 as the older version you are running might be buggy.